# mean of the select number of numerical values from a column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, mean

From the column Age I want to select age group between (15 & 45) and then replace the missing values with the mean of age group (15 & 45)

```
[IN]: train['Age'].isnull().value_counts()
[OUT]:
False    714
True     177
Name: Age, dtype: int64
```

how do I write this code?

Most solutions are referring to boolean based outputs

```
train['Age'].fillna((train['Age'] > 15 & train['Age'] < 45).mean())

TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [float64] array with a scalar of type [bool]

train['Age'].fillna((train['Age'] > 15 & train['Age'] < 45).mean())
```

Age groups are spread out between 1 and 80
From the column Age I want to select age group between (15 & 45) and then replace the missing values with the mean of age group (15 & 45)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add parentheses and `loc` for column `Age`:

```
m = train.loc[(train['Age'] > 15) & (train['Age'] < 45), 'Age'].mean()
```

Or use [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
m = train.loc[train['Age'].between(15, 45, inclusive=False), 'Age'].mean()
```

And laste replace missing values:

```
train['Age'] = train['Age'].fillna(m)
```

Comment: @VinBolisetti, please mark the answer as correct if it worked

Comment: @SridharThiagarajan sure, thanks for the letting me know, I don't know how stackoverflow works, I marked the answer as correct! :)

Answer (score -1):

```
train['Age'].fillna(train.Age[(train['Age'] > 15) & (train['Age'] < 45) ].mean())
```

Comment: Hello, please provide explanation when you post an answer. Also it seems that this is the same answer as @jezrael.

Comment: Not recomended this solution, because possible [`chained indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy), always use `loc`

Comment: Or better link is [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#evaluation-order-matters)